# Error when accessing #include <FF.au3>

Tags: autoit

I have added the following header file to my code:

```
#include <FF.au3>
```

When I try to access this library I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE\..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut "D:\My_Files\Automation scripts\My tests\AutomaticWebpageLogin -1.au3"    
D:\My_Files\Automation scripts\My tests\AutomaticWebpageLogin -1.au3 (1) : ==> Error opening the file.: 
#include <FF.au3> 
Exit code: 1    Time: 0.411`
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Where did you place your `FF.au3`?

Comment: i placed it in header file.

Comment: @user3485027: Sumsar1812 meant where you placed the file "FF.au3" on your harddisk. You have to include the file like this: `#include "C:\some\path\FF.au3"`.

Comment: Or if you want to keep using `#include <FF.au3>` then you can place the file in `..autoit\AutoIt3\Include`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. First you need to download [FF.au3](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0601b-10/) and put it in the same dir as
   your script or the autoit include files dir.
2. Then you need to download and install [MozRepl](http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl)
3. Don't forget to start MozRepl. FF-menu: Extras/Menu or check there
   "Activate on startup".

Comment: Hello Milos, can you still create automation using that UDF to control the new version of FireFox via MozRepl? It seems not working and I can't find how to start MozRepl in the new version.

Comment: @5ervant No, I didn't use FF.au3 in a very long time. I suggest you check https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167661-ffau3-v0601b-15/?page=1 and https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0601b-10/

Comment: Thanks for replying, I already got an answer at: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167661-ffau3-v0601b-15/?page=2#comment-1268506